# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ScrollView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: java, android

When user clicks on stars in ClassOne.java another activity opens which is ClassTwo.java. Then user types in review & clicks on the check mark which submits the review & takes them back to ClassOne.java & displays their written review under "Reviews" which has a TextView.

When i click on the check to submit i keep getting the error. How can i fix this error ?

[ClassOne.java Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9ZsP.png)
[ClassTwo.java Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AIgm.png)

```
ClassTwo.java    

public ImageView sumbitCheck;
public Textview reviewDisplay;

submitCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //submit check image
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); //TextView inside ClassOne.java
            TextView text = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ClassOne, null);
            reviewDisplay = (TextView) text.findViewById(R.id.display_review);


            Intent intent = new Intent(ClassTwo.this, ClassOne.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

ClassOne.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scroll_view">

        <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout5"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/display_review" />
        </RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView>
```

ClassTwo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#257985"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout6"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Chipotle Chicken Fajitas"
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/submit_check"
        android:src="@drawable/submitarrow"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout7">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="You&apos;re Review"
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:scaleX=".5"
        android:scaleY=".4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

   </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:hint="What did you think?"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="#e8e5e5"
    android:id="@+id/users_review" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use this `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ClassOne, null);`

Comment: use  `View text = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ClassOne, null);`

Comment: @sushildlh no need of casting , it's `return` type is already a `View`

Comment: thanks guys i got it!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below line in your `ClassTwo.java`:

```
 TextView text = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ClassOne, null);
```

Here layout xml file `ClassOne.xml` has root as a `ScrollView`. So when you will inflate that layout, you need to cast it as `ScrollView` or `View` parent of all views.

It is good practice to cast every inflated layout as `View` and then get all different views using `findViewById()`.

So change your line as below:

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ClassOne, null);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Intent to change text of a textView which is of another Activity from current Activity.

In current Activity:-

```
Intent intent= new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,CallingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key","Review changed from a different activity");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

In onCreate() of your calling Activity:-

```
Intent mIntent=getIntent();
        if(mIntent!=null){
            String msg=mIntent.getStringExtra("key");
            textView.setText(msg);
        }
```